# How to change file upload URL in CKFinder 2.2 using Java

Tags: java, spring, ckeditor, ckfinder

I am using CKFinder-2.2 with CKEditor-3.5.X and all was well until I tried to upload an image/file and send that to image. I got the following error when I tried to send the file to the server `No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/my-project/ckfinder/core/connector/java/connector.java] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'`. I am using Spring MVC 3 for this web application.

The **browse server** button with **upload** button works just fine as I made the required changes in the `<url-pattern>` in `web.xml` to get it working, but I can't send the file to the server using **the send it to the server** button.

[image]

I think the error occurred due to following lines in `CKFinderSetupCKEditor.java`:

```
private static final String CKFINDER_UPLOAD_URL = "/ckfinder/core/connector/java/connector.java?command=QuickUpload&type=";
private static final String CKFINDER_PAGE = "/ckfinder.html";
```

I tried the `config` attribute of `<ckeditor:replace>` as well as mentioned below but that did not help either.

```
<%@ page import="com.ckeditor.CKEditorConfig" %>
<%
    CKEditorConfig settings = new CKEditorConfig();
    settings.addConfigValue("filebrowserUploadUrl", "/my-project/resources/ckfinder/core/connector/java/connector.java?command=QuickUpload&type=Files");
    settings.addConfigValue("filebrowserImageUploadUrl", "/my-project/resources/ckfinder/core/connector/java/connector.java?command=QuickUpload&type=Images");
    settings.addConfigValue("filebrowserFlashUploadUrl", "/my-project/resources/ckfinder/core/connector/java/connector.java?command=QuickUpload&type=Flash");
%>
    <ckfinder:setupCKEditor basePath="/my-project/resources/ckfinder/" editor="editor1" />  
    <ckeditor:replace replace="editor1" basePath="/my-project/resources/ckeditor/" config="<%=setting>"/>
```

Could someone help me understand what am I doing wrong here and how to get it done? It's just a file I want to upload to my server. It should not be too difficult.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone comes across the same issue, adding the following got things working for me:

**web.xml**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ConnectorServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.ckfinder.connector.ConnectorServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>XMLConfig</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>debug</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ConnectorServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>
        /resources/ckfinder/core/connector/java/connector.java
    </url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>FileUploadFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.ckfinder.connector.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>sessionCookieName</param-name>
                <param-value>JSESSIONID</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>sessionParameterName</param-name>
                <param-value>jsessionid</param-value>
            </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>FileUploadFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>
        /resources/ckfinder/core/connector/java/connector.java
     </url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

**.jsp file where you want ckeditor and ckfinder integrated to the textarea**

```
<%@ page import="com.ckeditor.CKEditorConfig" %>
<% 
    CKEditorConfig settings = new CKEditorConfig();
    settings.addConfigValue("filebrowserBrowseUrl","/myapp/resources/ckfinder/ckfinder.html");
    settings.addConfigValue("filebrowserImageBrowseUrl","/myapp/resources/ckfinder/ckfinder.html?type=Images");
    settings.addConfigValue("filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl","/myapp/resources/ckfinder/ckfinder.html?type=Flash");
    settings.addConfigValue("filebrowserUploadUrl","/myapp/resources/ckfinder/core/connector/java/connector.java?command=QuickUpload&type=Files");
    settings.addConfigValue("filebrowserImageUploadUrl","/myapp/resources/ckfinder/core/connector/java/connector.java?command=QuickUpload&type=Images");
    settings.addConfigValue("filebrowserFlashUploadUrl","/myapp/resources/ckfinder/core/connector/java/connector.java?command=QuickUpload&type=Flash");
%>

<ckeditor:replace replace="editor1" basePath="/myapp/resources/ckeditor/" config="<%=settings %>" />
```